# Download Screenshot in PDF on button click in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pdf, printpdf, lightning-button

I have a lightning component which displays list of accounts in table. And I need to create a button. On clicking , screenshot of the screen should be downloaded as PDF/excel file.

I am not sure how to proceed on this. I know I have to use JS library but don't really know how can I use this. Please let me know or provide any helpful links.

Answer (score 2):

You will require jspdf in the lightning component. Include it with ltng:require and then call a function on the button click.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/7806/) which you can have a look.

Comment: Can I ask you to explain bit more of any sample code. I am new to lightning and would need bit more help